# How to create a table in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

How do I (or rather, what do I write) a `SQL CREATE TABLE` command to create a table for `Term` as defined in the picture to create a table?

I am completely new to `mhphpadmin (sql)` and am learning this from scratch.

[image]

Comment: I have already installed the XAMPP and mhphpadmin is up and running.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. Refer to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also if you get an answer to you question you should try to mark as accept so that other users can be benefited, you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to get more info about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general syntax is

```
Create Table Table_name (Column_name1 DataType, Column_name2 DataType,...)
```

You can create table as

```
CREATE TABLE Term (Term_Name VARCHAR(25), Term_StartDate DATE, TermEndDate DATE);
```

Comment: thank you. it took a few minutes, but it seems that i needed to drop down those and make sure each command had a line.

Comment: question. How can i just select the Term Spring 2 2014 and its Term_StartDate and Term_EndDate only? I do not need the two other rows.

Comment: You can use where clause. For more details I suggest you to please go through the following tutorial of [MySql](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial.aspx).